# Emscripten Error while installing

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I downloaded the emscripten files from github. Then used the following commands:
1. emsdk update
2. emsdk install latest

When I use the second command, it get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Batman\Desktop\webassembly\emsdk-master>emsdk install latest
Installing SDK 'sdk-1.38.3-64bit'..
Installing tool 'clang-e1.38.3-64bit'..
Downloading: C:/Users/Batman/Desktop/webassembly/emsdk-master/zips/emscripten-llvm-e1.38.3.zip from https://s3.amazonaws.com/mozilla-games/emscripten/packages/llvm/tag/win_64bit/emscripten-llvm-e1.38.3.zip, 291452825 Bytes
 Error downloading URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mozilla-games/emscripten/packages/llvm/tag/win_64bit/emscripten-llvm-e1.38.3.zip': [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Installation failed!
```

Anyone has any idea of how to resolve this issue. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: That download URL works fine for me. I'd guess this is a networking problem at your end, or a proxy server somewhere between you and AWS? We probably can't help with that sorry.

Comment: @Rup I am not using any proxy. Still, I am encountering this error. The issue has been reported on Github as well, but no one seems to know how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading the files, clone them from GitHub. Then, run the commands as per the instructions and you'll be good to go.

Comment: But isn't this listing from the standard way of installing Emscripten through `emsdk`? It looks familiar for me (but I'm on Ubuntu, not Windows, and I choose option to compile the `incoming` branch locally).

Comment: The first method mentioned was for downloading the files and not cloning. When I downloaded the files, I wasn't able to update. When I cloned the file, I was able to use all commands.